# Dynamic Options for AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass dynamic variables into a directive that displays a time picker (pickadate.js: http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/). However, I am struggling on how to get the options into the directive. I am scoured the internet, but see a multitude of approaches, and am confused on how best to construct this as it is not working. Here is my current code:

Directive:

```
// Pick a date directive used as pick-a-time on HTML element
appDirectives.directive('pickATime', function() {
    return {
        // Restrict it to be an attribute in this case
        restrict: 'A',
        // responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.pickatime(scope.$eval(attrs.pickATime));
        },
        scope: {
            timeOptions: '=options'
        },
        templateUrl: '../Templates/timeoptions.html'
    };
});
```

Directive Template:

```
Min: {{timeOptions.startTime}} Max: {{customerInfo.endTime}}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" id="timestart" pick-a-time options="timeRange" data-ng-model="itemtimestart" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
```

Controller to pass in dynamic values (stored in REST)

```
// Query settings for variables to be used later in function
appSettings.query(function(settings) {
    // Data is within an object of "value", so this pushes the server side array into a variable
    var setting = settings.value;

    // Foreach result, where setting is equal to active get the apporpriate variables
    angular.forEach(setting, function(settingvalue, settingkey) {
        if (settingvalue.Title == 'Active') {

            // Get work and non work durations as variables
            workDuration = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_Hours_x0020;
            nonWorkDuration = settingvalue.Non_x0020_Work_x0020_Day_x0020_H;

            // Get $scope variables to control time picker range
            var startHour = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_Start_x0020.split(":")[0];
            var startMinute = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_Start_x0020.split(":")[1];
            var startTime = '[' + startHour + ',' + startMinute + ']';
            var endHour = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_End_x0020_M.split(":")[0];
            var endMinute = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_End_x0020_M.split(":")[1];    
            var endTime = '[' + endHour + ',' + endMinute + ']';
            $scope.timeRange = {min: startTime, max: endTime};                  
        }
    })
});
```

The non-dynamic method (which works) on an input is as follows:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="End Time" id="timeend" pick-a-time="{min: [0,0], max: [23,30]}" data-ng-model="itemtimeend"class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
```

**Update:** Working with Dave, I have adjusted to the following. It logs the timeRange correctly, but gives an undefined for the timeOptions in the directive

timeRange Log:

```
 time start is [8,30]time end is [17,0]
```

timeOption log:

```
 time options log undefined
```

Directive (timeOptions undefined on logging):

```
appDirectives.directive('pickATime', function() {
return {
    // Restrict it to be an attribute in this case
    restrict: 'A',
    // responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.pickatime(scope.pickATime);
        console.log("time options log" + scope.timeOptions);
    },
    scope: {
        timeOptions: '='

    },
    templateUrl: '../Templates/timeoptions.html'
};

});
```

Template:

```
min: {{timeOptions.min}}, max: {{timeOptions.max}}
```

Controller (logs out correctly):

```
// Get $scope variables to control time picker range
var startHour = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_Start_x0020.split(":")[0];
var startMinute = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_Start_x0020.split(":")[1];
var startTime = '[' + startHour + ',' + startMinute + ']';
var endHour = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_End_x0020_M.split(":")[0];
var endMinute = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_End_x0020_M.split(":")[1];
var endTime = '[' + endHour + ',' + endMinute + ']';
$scope.timeRange = {
    min: startTime,
    max: endTime
};
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" id="timestart" pick-a-time timeOptions="timeRange" data-ng-model="itemtimestart" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
```

**Update - Picker Working... but Now Form is not Submitting Time Data** per this Post: [TimePicker directive won't submit time (undefined)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681821/timepicker-directive-wont-submit-time-undefined)**

Huge thanks to @dave-alperovich and @joe-enzminger for tireless help and great answers.

Controller:

```
// Get $scope variables to control time picker range
var startHour = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_Start_x0020.split(":")[0];
var startMinute = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_Start_x0020.split(":")[1];
var endHour = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_End_x0020_M.split(":")[0];
var endMinute = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_End_x0020_M.split(":")[1];
$scope.timeRange = {
min: [startHour,startMinute],
max: [endHour,endMinute]
};
```

Directive:

```
appDirectives.directive('pickATime', function() {
return {
    // Restrict it to be an attribute in this case
    restrict: 'A',
    // responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.pickatime(scope.options());
    },
    scope: {
        options: '&pickATime'
    },
};
});
```

Usage:

```
<input ng-if="timeRange" type="text" placeholder="Start Time" id="timestart" pick-a-time="timeRange" data-ng-model="itemtimestart" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different ways to pass data from a parent scope into a directive.  You've chosen (correctly) the class of choices offered by isolated scopes, as indicated by the

```
scope: {
}
```

parameter of your directive.  This means that the scope of your directive will not prototypically inherit from the parent scope.

The reason your first example doesn't work is that the line:

```
element.pickatime(scope.$eval(attrs.pickATime));
```

ends up passing undefined to the element.pickatime() method.

This is because what this line of code does is attempt to evaluate the expression (which is a string) contained in the value of the pick-a-time html attribute from your DOM against the directive's scope.  The value of the pick-a-time attribute is an empty string in your first example.

When you use the "non dynamic" version, the value of the pick-a-time attribute is now the string

```
"{min: [0,0], max: [23,30]}"
```

Which is a valid angular expression and $eval will return an object with min and max properties set to [0,0] and [23,30] respectively, so your directive works.

In both cases, your directive completely ignores the value passed in to the directive with the options attribute.

An easy fix would be to modify your directive to use the information passed in via the options attribute.  The way your directive is written, this object will be two-way bound to the $scope.timeOptions value (more on this later).  Essentially, any changes to $scope.timeOptions will show up in the parent scope's timeRange property, and vice versa.

The change to your directive would be to use:

```
element.pickatime(scope.timeOptions);
```

Extra credit:

In your last example, you state that timeOptions is undefined in the directive.  This is because the html needs to be:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Start Time" id="timestart" pick-a-time time-options="timeRange" data-ng-model="itemtimestart" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
```

The only change is timeOptions -> time-options

This is how angular handles attribute to scope property mapping by convention.

Extra Extra Credit:

Your example does not require two-way binding (I don't think you want to change the options inside the directive).  You can avoid the creation of two $watches by using & instead of =.  This would be my final version of your directive:

```
appDirectives.directive('pickATime', function() {
    return {
        // Restrict it to be an attribute in this case
        restrict: 'A',
        // responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.pickatime(scope.options());
        },
        scope: {
            options: '&pickATime'
        },
        templateUrl: '../Templates/timeoptions.html'
    };
});
```

with usage:

UPDATE for dot notation issue:

In your controller, you need to use dot notation for itemtimestart:

```
.controller('xxx', function($scope){
    $scope.parameters = {
    }
}

<input ng-if="timeRange" type="text" placeholder="Start Time" id="timestart" pick-a-time="timeRange" data-ng-model="parameters.itemtimestart" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">

$scope.paramters.itemtimestart should now be the correct time.
```

You can also simplify this by using the "controller as" syntax.

[Here is a Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/J4uBYAcAFvR8qCocxT5N?p=preview)

Comment: `element.pickatime(scope.options())` I am thinking scope.options would be an object not a function.

Comment: It returns this in the DOM and does not filter the time. <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding ng-isolate-scope picker__input ng-touched" id="timestart" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-readonly="false" aria-owns="timestart_root" type="text" readonly="" placeholder="Start Time" data-ng-model="itemtimestart" autocomplete="off" pick-a-time="timeRange">min: , max:

Comment: My template is currently: min: {{options.min}}, max: {{options.max}} is this correct?

Comment: @Scottux, actually, no.  & bindings create a function that, when called, return the value returned by evaluating the expression (the string value of the html attribute) against the parent scope.

Comment: @Kode, this is probably because the input is being created before the timeRange information is retrieved from your server.  You can verify by adding an ng-if.  I've added this to my edited answer.   You can also do this in the directive by using a $watch, but ng-if accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: @Kode, also your template (in my example), would be min: {{options().min}}, max: {{options().max}}

Comment: Also, keep in mind that when you use a template in the way you are doing, the contents of the input element will be replaced with the contents of the template.  input elements usually don't have content at all in valid html.

Comment: That was the missing piece. Given this, I don't need the template since we are putting straight to the HTML attribute, and I updated my timeRange reference. My updates are in the code.

Comment: Just noticed that when I changed the directive, it doesn't recognize the time when I submit my form, but throws an undefined error.

Comment: @Kode, I think this implementation needs a function: `$scope.timeRange = function() { return {min: startTime, max: endTime} };` and the pass thru would be `pick-a-time="timeRange()"` ... I didn't notice that we were over-writing the reference. You need a function that sends the "current values" every time the $digest cycle runs

Comment: No such luck. It is still returning as undefined when submitting the form. Does ng-if conflict with ng-model?

Comment: @Kode, this part is confusing: `scope: {
        options: '&pickATime'
    },`  now when you use options, it must be as a function too : `var time = options();`

Comment: I just tried it this way, but got undefined again. Maybe we can put a $watch on the scope to see if it populates. appDirectives.directive('pickATime', function() {
    return {
        require: '?appItemPostCtrl',
  restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.pickatime(scope.timeOptions);
        },
    };
});

Comment: @DaveAlperovich - shouldn't be necessary to make timeRange a function.  What exactly is undefined?  $scope.itemtimestart?

Comment: Yes, it is $scope.itemtimestart that is undefined. if I remove the ng-if and set the values manually (ex. pick-a-time="min: [9,0], max:[14,30]" it submits but I need the min/max to be dynamic

Comment: @JoeEnzminger, I think it has to be a function. You can't pass timeRange  by reference, because it is being over-written with a new object every digest cycle. Binding to timeRange  the first time only passes a reference to the object timeRange points to at the moment. A function will pass a new object every cycle.

Comment: @Kode, seems you need ng-if in case timeRange is undefined. If timeRange() becomes a function that does all calculations by passing settingvalue, then your function can return dummy values if settingvalue is not set yet. This way you can avoid the ng-if.

Comment: @Kode, I undeleted my answer to show what I mean. Use a global Getter that returns a dummy value if null. Then you don't need ng-if

Comment: Makes sense. It is throwing an error on the GetTimeRange "Expected an assignment or function and instead saw a expression". Changed it to this, but its not filtering the time:       $scope.timeRange = null;
      $scope.GetTimeRange = function() {
       if ($scope.timeRange === null) return {
        min: [9, 0],
        max: [14, 30]
       }; else return $scope.timeRange
      }

Comment: @Kode, i changed my approach a touch. LMK if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Console logs properly at the controller level, but not changing the range.

Comment: The reason it is null is that ng-if creates a scope, which brings the dot notation problem into play.  I've updating my answer for you (well, it will be updated in a few minutes :)

Comment: Irrespective of the solution, I am learning so much from you and @DaveAlperovich

Comment: Glad to help.  I'm trying to put together a plunk for you

Comment: What is the controller as?

Comment: When specify a controller on a dom element <div ng-controller="main as vm"></div>, it will add the controller instance to the scope as the property "vm".

Comment: As my controllers are tied to my page via the App, I went with the parameters $scope and it is working. I will likely use vm in the future

Answer (score 0):

If the options is already there ( in `timeRange`) and will not change over time, you have nothing to do: it should be in `scope.timeOptions` (both in your link and controller).

However if the options can change at any time and you want to refresh the composant when it does, you need to watch for its changes:

```
scope.$watch('timeOptions', function(newOptions) {
  // do something with the newOptions
});
```

Comment: So my code should be working? Since updates rarely occur? At this point, the timepicker is not reflecting the variables

Comment: What are you supposed to do with the options? If you just need to display them in your template, indeed this should be enough.

Comment: I need to use them as variables in the directive to control the time range.

Comment: You have them in `scope.timeOptions`, I don't know what to say more, do you have any specific question?

Comment: They are not changing the time picker, but if insert the hard values in the timepicker it works. It's odd, it should work as you stated but it's not

Comment: This is very confusing use case and many advanced users intuitively make this mistake, When you pass a variable name, it does NOT need to be evaluated. An object expression like `{min: [0,0], max: [23,30]}` does need to be evaluated. That's why OP had success with "hard coded values" -- notation, but failed due to the attempt to `$eval` a variable name.