# TimePicker directive won't submit time (undefined)

Tags: angularjs

I was able to get my timepicker to display a time range dynamically as seen in this post: [Dynamic Options for AngularJS Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422269/dynamic-options-for-angularjs-directive)

However, when using this approach, it won't submit the time on my form. It states it is undefined when having this usage:

```
<input ng-if="timeOptions" type="text" placeholder="Start Time" id="timestart" pick-a-time="timeOptions" data-ng-model="itemtimestart" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
```

It worked before I attempted to dynamically set the timerange, but with a previous version of the directive:

```
appDirectives.directive('pickATime', function() {
return {
    // Restrict it to be an attribute in this case
    restrict: 'A',
    // responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.pickatime(scope.$eval(attrs.pickATime));
    },
};
});
```

The previous usage looked like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="End Time" id="timeend" pick-a-time="{min: [0,0], max: [23,30]}" data-ng-model="itemtimeend" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
```

It appears the ng-model is not getting picked up on submit, but I don't see where. My directive is currently:

```
appDirectives.directive('pickATime', function() {
return {
    // Restrict it to be an attribute in this case
    restrict: 'A',
    // responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.pickatime(scope.options());
    },
    scope: {
        options: '&pickATime'
    },
};
});
```

My controller is as follows: (Which works for have a constrained time range

```
// Get $scope variables to control time picker range
var startHour = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_Start_x0020.split(":")[0];
var startMinute = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_Start_x0020.split(":")[1];
var endHour = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_End_x0020_M.split(":")[0];
var endMinute = settingvalue.Work_x0020_Day_x0020_End_x0020_M.split(":")[1];
$scope.timeOptions = { // full options listed at: http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/
min: [startHour,startMinute],
max: [endHour,endMinute],
};
```

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem in a plunk I will help you debug it.

Comment: There is a decent amount of code, but I will give it a try!